# Regex error while using DiskLruCache (Jake Wharton)

Tags: java, android, regex

I receive this error
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keys must match regex [a-z0-9_-]{1,64}: "mision_imposible_–_rogue_nation"`

can anybody see where is the error cause i cant figure out whats wrong with that movie title and why its not complying with the Regex format

Comment: Is that a short dash or a long dash between imposible and rouge? If short, is the string 64 characters long? (can't check easily on phone)

Comment: Indeed that seems to be a long dash rather than a hyphen.

Comment: @PhilippeA   i am not sure if that is a long dash cause i am getting the data from a JSON feed and yes the length is less than 64 chars

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it is less than 64 chars

Comment: @FrankNStein thanks for the editing and sorry for the mistake

Comment: Try doing a string replace on that dash character with just a hyphen and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @cricket_007 okay let me try

Comment: `–` and `-` are different characters, no matter where they come from. the lib doesn't accept `–` as key thus the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

We can do better shaping the input string according to the requests of DiskLruCache:

- Max length: 64 chars
- Character class allowed: `[a-z0-9_-]`

So assuming the input string `input` is not null the code below do the trick:

```
final String MAX_LENGTH = 64;
//First check is used to avoid exception
(input.length() > MAX_LENGTH ? input.substring(0,MAX_LENGTH) : input)
 .toLowerCase()                 // All alphabetic ascii to lowercase
 .replaceAll("[^a-z0-9_-]","_") // Replace not permitted char with "_"
```

Comment: Hi, you can also do the following to the regex  you wrote  ((\p{Pd})\1) on that demo.

Comment: @GsusRecovery thanks for the help and it is working perfectly also i thought of a work around here it is tell me what do you think               {String bitmapKey = movieTitle.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^\\w+]", "_");}

Comment: @dEv_tO_bE: i've updated the answer to shape the input string according the DiskLruCache criteria

Comment: @GsusRecovery even better that last edit is perfect and will avoid any different chars ..... and in my implementation i checked for the max length but in a different step cause i put it first into shape then i trim whatever exceeds the 64 chars limit thanks again

Comment: @dEv_tO_bE: glad to hear that, i'll leave the length check for SO future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this directly in Java regex, but on this regex editor all you need in your hyphen is to have a backward slash.

Here there is the option to have first the dash and last the hyphen.. otherwise omit the first one to only accept the hyphen. `[a-z0-9_\–]{1,64}`

http://regexr.com/3cahm See if this works.